# Joint Distribution, find $P(X-Y>z)$

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have joint density $f(x,y)=2$ for $0<y<x<1$. I want to find this expression: $P(X-Y>z)$. So:
\begin{align}
P(X-Y>z) = P(X \geq z, Y \leq X-z) &= \int\limits_{z}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{x-z} 2 \ dy \ dx \\
&= \int\limits_{z}^{1} \big[2y\big]_{y=0}^{y=x-z} \ dx \\
&= \int\limits_{z}^{1} 2x -2z \ dx \\
&= \big[ x^2 -2zx \big]_{x=z}^{x=1} \\
&= 1 -2z - (z^2 - 2z^2) \\
&= z^2 -2z +1 \\
&= (z-1)^2
\end{align}
Which is incorrect, because the correct answer is $\frac{(z-1)^2}{2}$. What is wrong and why? I can not see it.

Comment: "because the correct answer is (z−1)^2/2" Who says so? Note that for z=0, one must find P(X-Y>0) = 1, not 1/2.

Answer (score 2):

$P(X-Y>z)= P(Y < X-z).$ $\{Y < X-z\}$ means that $(X,Y)$ fall in the grey area below. Besides $(X,Y)$ fall in the larger triangle with probability one. The area of the large triangle is $\frac{1}{2}$, the area of the grey tianle is $\frac{(1-z)^2}{2}$.

So, I think that you are right:

$$P(X-Y>z)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{ if }& z<0\\
(1-z)^2,&\text{ if }&0\le z <1\\
0,&\text{ if }&1\le z.
\end{cases}$$

[image]

Comment: @Did: Thank you. I know that the rest is trivial. If trivial, then why to do double integration? (The only reason to answer...)